# Choose different keyboard layout

Tags: 14.04, keyboard-layout

I cant't find where I can choose a different keyboard layout. `Unity control center` `Keyboard` and `Language support` doesn't helped.

How can I add new Latvian keyboard layout?

Comment: @mpi What makes you think that the vico doesn't want to add a new keyboard layout?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the top of your screen on the desktop, you should see a small box with "En" written on it - if you have English as your keyboard layout. Click on it, after that you should see a drop-down list. Click on "text entry settings". This should open a text entry window. On the left of the window, there is a box called "Input sources to use". Click on the "+" option and you should find a Latvian keyboard layout. Hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

Just open terminal and write

> sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration